# Unity - Humanoid character animations not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, blender

I have some simple animations made in blender.
I used Rigify to rig my character and then I used an add on rigify to unity to make my rig ready for unity. Then I brought my charcter in Unity. Every thing works fine with generic character but if I convert it to humanoid(which I want to use) It break and This is what I see. Deformings works perfectly in blender but the problem occurs in Unity using Humanoid character.

**[Video of problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1aFnCVGenS0)**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

What I have tried:

- Reparenting the model to the rig
- Checking the weight paints

I am very bad with rigging and animations related stuff. Any help will be really appreciated thank you.